# removing an Icon from home screen but not uninstalling them,

Tags: home-screen, app-drawer

I want to remove an icon shortcut from home screen. But not uninstalling them. OS is Lollipop and rooted. Is any way to hide an icon from home screen by terminal emulator. I don't want to change to nova launcher or any other app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify: from the *homescreen (workspace)*, or from the *app drawer*? If it's the former case, you should be able to drag anything off the workspace into a "remove" icon fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you tap and hold the icon, you should see a option at the top of the screen to remove or uninstall it. Choose remove.